# AVA Test Runner Setup with Create React App Boilerplate

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, ava

Trying to setup AVA after running create-react-app. There are a few tutorials and references of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kimochg/1f1a0c453d5898a26c45eb9d0ff3552d) I've found and tried, but I keep getting an `unexpected token` error on the JSX `<App />` element. Anyone know what is wrong with that gist? Full output of `npm run test`:

```
react-with-ava@0.1.0 test /react-with-ava
cross-env NODE_ENV=test ava

1 exception

Uncaught Exception
SyntaxError: /react-with-ava/src/App.test.js: Unexpected token (8:18)
SyntaxError: /react-with-ava/src/App.test.js: Unexpected token (8:18)
6 | test('renders without crashing', t => {
7 |   const div = document.createElement('div');
8 |   ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
  |                   ^
9 | });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is neither supported nor recommended to use Ava with Create React App.

The created project already contains a test runner (Jest) which we recommend to use. Run `npm test` in the project folder to start.

In theory you could get Ava to work but this would require configuring Babel which will get confusing in a CRA project very quickly. If you insist on using Ava you can `npm run eject` and then replace Jest with Ava manually in the ejected project.